# Why do programmers use void*

Tags: c, pointers, void, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm learning about dynamics data structure e.g. `malloc` function.
Why sometimes programmers use `void*` as a pointer parameter to (for example) dynamic variables of integers and chars? What are the differences?
What are the advantages?

Comment: @user1 Unclear questions that demonstrate no research effort are not worth the time spent editing them. They end up closed anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every pointer type can be cast to `void*` safely. Generic functions that need to work with pointers of all sorts of objects, such as `malloc` and `realloc` can work only if they use `void*` in their interface.

Comment: There is not much more you can add to that. A complete explanation in 2-sentences -- those are rare in the world.

Comment: Thanks @DavidC.Rankin :)